# apache2 virtual site not reachable

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

i am setting up the bloodhound webapp, and everything worked fine and i wanted to integrate it into the apache2 webserver using the [a official guide](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall),
but apache is not listening to my specified port (tryed 8081 and 8082)
i testet with browser/telnet/netstat, and i get no error in the logs.

Its runs on a Debian Wheezy

/etc/apache2/sites-available/bloodhound

```
 <VirtualHost *:8081>
   WSGIDaemonProcess bh_tracker user=tmbloodhound python-path=/home/tmbloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   WSGIScriptAlias /bloodhound /home/tmbloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/site/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
   <Directory /home/tmbloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/site/cgi-bin>
     WSGIProcessGroup bh_tracker
     WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
   <LocationMatch "/bloodhound/[^/]+/login">
     AuthType Digest
     AuthName "Bloodhound"
     AuthDigestDomain /bloodhound
     AuthUserFile /home/tmbloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.7/installer/environments/main/bloodhound.htdigest
     Require valid-user
   </LocationMatch>
 </VirtualHost>
```

### apache2ctl -S => apache knows the site

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:8081                 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bloodhound:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

### netstat -i => doesnt look like appache is listening to 8081 at all.

```
root@chronis2:~# netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:submission    *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 localhost:8005          [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*
udp        0      0 *:36676                 *:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:57632              [::]:*
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1614614872 /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1614614831 /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1614614721 /var/run/apache2/wsgi.17360.0.1.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1614615680 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1614638717 /var/run/sendmail/mta/smcontrol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you edit /etc/apache2/ports.conf and add **Listen** section there?

> Listen 8081

Comment: no, thx will check that

Comment: thx, that was the solution :))